# Give GRUB Control To Another OS

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub2, dual-boot, parrotsec

i have triple boot Windows-10,Mint 19,Parrot Linux. after the last install (parrot) the grub menu got updated to parrot GRUB menu style which i believe parrot got control of the boot menu (that's what i wanted), so after it i had a problem with the windows 10 not booting tried to repair it with (boot-repair) from Linux Mint then the GRUB menu got updated to the Mint GRUB menu style. i still can boot to Parrot-Os Normally from Linux Mint's grub menu ! , now i decided to remove Linux Mint partition the but i'm afraid that i'll screw up somehow.

i tried this [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455129/dual-boot-kali-and-mint-want-to-use-grub-of-mint) doing `grub-install /dev/sdb && sudo update-grub`  but it didn't work.

**so how can i give back the GRUB menu control to Parrot Linux And remove the Linux Mint Safely?**

**Thank You In Advance !!!!**

Some Infos About The Partitioning :

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[Windows-10-HD]
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
|-sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part
|-sda2   8:2    0 194.8G  0 part
`-sda3   8:3    0 270.5G  0 part

sdb      8:16   0 298.1G  0 disk
[MINT-PARTITION]
|-sdb1   8:17   0   136G  0 part
[PARROT-PARTITION]
|-sdb2   8:18   0  94.1G  0 part /
|-sdb3   8:19   0  66.2G  0 part /home
`-sdb4   8:20   0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you should be able to change boot order in UEFI boot menu. post this: `sudo efibootmgr -v` or change order in UEFI settings menu. If BIOS just reinstall grub to MBR or use Boot-Repair's advanced options to choose install & drive.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: it's BIOS i have UEFI too but i got it disabled

Comment: Just boot into the install you want to keep and use Boot-Repair or just install grub to MBR. `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` if inside your working install. Where sdX is drive your want grub installed in & BIOS boot from.